# How to pass widget constructor as a parameter for another widget to build

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to pass one widget as a parameter to another?

My code has something similar to this with two `TextWidget` of type `BoldWidget` and `ItalicWidget`:

```
abstract class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  TextWidget({
    @required this.text,
  });
}

class BoldWidget extends TextWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(this.text, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
  }
}

class ItalicWidget extends TextWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(this.text, style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),);
  }
}
```

At runtime, I want to pass in either `TextWidget` as an argument to another widget (`TextDisplay`) like this:

```
class TextDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextWidget widget;
  final String string;

  const TextDisplay({Key key, this.widget, this.string}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget(string);
  }
}
```

What doesn't work in the code above is `widget(string)`, with error message "'widget' isn't a function".

How can I pass one widget as another argument so it can constructed by another class?

My actual code can't build the `TextWidget` before passing it to `TextDisplay` as `TextDisplay` needs to apply some of the arguments to the `TextWidget`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the CallBack pattern using typedef :

```
  typedef CustomCallBack = TextWidget Function(String value);

  class TextDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
    final CustomCallBack widget;
    final String string;

    const TextDisplay({Key key, this.widget, this.string}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return widget(string);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it's good but now I'am getting this error
`The argument type 'ProfileCards' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function<T>({T data})'.`
How to get around this?

Comment: @ASADHAMEED I don't know if this will help you, but I was struggling to get this to work until I realised I had to send the Widget as a function. Hard for me to explain but maybe this helps:

TypeDef:

```typedef OpenWidgetType = Widget Function();```

Parameter in class:

```final OpenWidgetType openWidget;```

When calling Widget, enter the parameter as:

`openWidget: () {
return WidgetToPass();
}`