# How to pass Future<Either<Response, List<dynamic>>> function as parameter to Widget?

Tags: flutter

I created a general ListPage as below:

```
class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final context;
  final Future<Either<Response, List<dynamic>>> futureFuncion;
  final classListItem, classDetailPage;

  const ListPage(this.context,this.futureFuncion,this.classListItem,this.classDetailPage, {Key key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(children: [Expanded(child: _getData())]));
  }

  FutureBuilder _getData() {
    return FutureBuilder<Either<ResponseError, List>>(
      future: futureFuncion,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Either<ResponseError, List>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return globals.showSnapshotError(snapshot);
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return globals.showLoading('Loading...');
        } else {
          return snapshot.data.fold((l) {
            return Error().showError(l.error, l.errorDescription);
          }, (r) {
            return ListView(children: _buildList(context, r));
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I use code as below to create List Page:

```
class RequestListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String url = globals.debug ? 'assets/data/list.json' : 'domain.com/list';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(toolbarHeight: 50,centerTitle: true,title: Text("List")),
      body: ListPage(
        context,
        debug
            ? LoadDataFromJsonFile().loadListData(context, url, '$Response')
            : RequestApi().getListData(url, '$Response'),
        RequestListItem,
        RequestDetailPage,
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildList(context, list) {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    list.forEach((item) {
      children.add(_buildTile(context, item));
    });
    return ListView(children: children);
  }
  ListTile _buildTile(context, item) {
    return ListTile(
      title: _buildListItem(context, item),
      onTap: () => showDetail(context, item),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildListItem(context, item) {
    return classListItem;
  }
  void showDetail(context, item) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => classDetailPage(context, item)),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this code, I got error as below, what can I do?

```
Attempted to use type 'RequestListItem' as a function. Since types do not define a method 'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to call the RequestListItem constructor and forget the 'new' operator?
Receiver: RequestListItem
Tried calling: RequestListItem(Instance of 'StatefulElement', Instance of 'Response')
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.google.com/search?q=send+data+to+another+screen+flutter . Sending data to another screen is the same thing as sending data to another widget. Everything in flutter is a widget.

Comment: I think that I got answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53310934/how-to-pass-widget-constructor-as-a-parameter-for-another-widget-to-build/53312484